# $and inside $elemMatch not working in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have the following query

```
{
    lessen: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $and: [
                    {start: {$lt: new Date()}},
                    {eind: {$gt: new Date()}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly until I updated to Meteor 0.8. Now it throws `Error: Unrecognized operator: $and`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I've got this issue too, but with $or.  Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the $and operator in this case you can simply write the query like this:

```
{
    lessen: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                start: {$lt: new Date()},
                eind: {$gt: new Date()}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good answer, the question asked how to use the $and operator, not how to refactor the code.